# How to load chart in Django Template

Tags: python, json, django, jinja2, altair

I have an Altair chart which I want to render in a Django Template. The chart is converted into a json object in the views. Here is the code

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        year = request.POST['year']
        
        df, cus_dict = generate_df(year)

        bar_obj = barGraphAltair(year, df)
        bar_obj = json.loads(bar_obj.to_json())
        print(bar_obj)

        context = {'bar': bar_obj}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**template**

```
<div id='altair-viz'>
    {% if bar %}
    {{ bar|safe }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

This just prints the json in the template. I know I have to use `Vega` to render the graph but I am not sure how to do that in jinja syntax

#### A temp solution

One way I got this to work, is by creating a different view and calling that view in the template as follows

**views.py**

```
def renderAltair(request):

    df, cus_dict = generate_df('2017')
    bar_obj = barGraphAltair('2017', df)

    bar_obj = json.loads(bar_obj.to_json())

    return JsonResponse(bar_obj)
```

**template**

```
<script>
vegaEmbed('#altair-viz', "{% url 'altair' %}")
</script>
```

This works, but as you can see from the original code, I get the year by submitting a form and passing that to the function for generating the graph. So I need the graph to be created in the home view

Comment: Have you used any kind of chart js? If not then try to use one of them

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
def home(request):
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        year = request.POST['year']
        context = {'year': year}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Not passing data in home view, will get that using json view.

template

```
<div id='altair-viz' data-url="{% url 'altair' %}?year={{year}}"></div>

<script>
    var data_url = $('#altair-viz').attr('data-url');
    vegaEmbed('#altair-viz', data_url)
</script>
```

and get data function

```
def renderAltair(request):
    year = request.GET.get('year')
    df, cus_dict = generate_df(year)
    bar_obj = barGraphAltair(year, df)

    bar_obj = json.loads(bar_obj.to_json())

    return JsonResponse(bar_obj)
```